# Storing large amounts of data persistently in Swift

Tags: swift, storage

I am currently making an app where I need to store large amounts of data persistently, much of which is contained within custom classes.

I am used to using UserDefault for storing data, but I have read that UserDefault doesn't work well with large amounts of data. What are my options, and is it possible to store it all by using UserDefault?

The game is a football manager game, and I have 30 teams, and every team has around 25 players, and every player has a long list of variables like games, goals, club etc that needs to be stored after each game

Comment: user defaults are not bad but you can go with a file (or multiple files) or a database. It really depends on your needs.

Comment: No, do not store data in UserDefaults.

Comment: I would suggest to start with NSCoding / NSKeyed​Archiver http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide more details about your data.

Comment: @nspavlo Why? With Swift 4 you should be using the new Codable features, not the old Objective-C NSCoding.

Comment: It's basically the same thing. I linked this article for comparison of Core Data to NSKeyedArchiver. Just create nice interface for your persistent store, later when it's necessary implementation can be changed without any issues.

Comment: @nspavlo No, the new Swift Codable is written in Swift. The old `NSCoding` requires that your Swift code take on a lot of unnecessary Objective-C baggage. And neither have anything to do with Core Data.

Comment: Codable will not store anything to disk by itself.

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16407594/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32951538/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24970074/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35762561/1187415

Comment: @nspavlo Of course not. Just as `NSCoding` doesn't by itself. You use something like `PropertyListEncoder/Decoder` and then write/read the `Data`.

Comment: You can use Codable protocol and save the json data locally or if needed upload it to a server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579322/2303865

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at Core Data, an Apple framework which helps you do exactly this: store large amounts of data persistently. Apple has loads of documentation. You might want to start here:

[Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

Comment: Core Data is also very complex. Sometimes using just files is better. It depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `Realm`. It abstracts the complexity of working with SQLite and it is easier than `Core Data`.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/